# Refresh Storyboard viewcontroller using swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, localization, viewcontroller

Im having button in all viewcontrollers to change language

**LanguageViewController.swift**

```
class LanguageViewController: UIViewController {
     @IBAction func actionChange(_ sender: Any) {
          L102Language.currentAppleLanguage()
          L102Language.setAppleLAnguageTo(lang: "en")
          // below code to refresh storyboard
          self.viewDidLoad()
     }
}
```

**L102Language.swift**

```
class func currentAppleLanguage() -> String{
        let userdef = UserDefaults.standard
        let langArray = userdef.object(forKey: APPLE_LANGUAGE_KEY) as! NSArray
        let current = langArray.firstObject as! String
        let endIndex = current.startIndex
        let currentWithoutLocale = current.substring(to: current.index(endIndex, offsetBy: 2))
        return currentWithoutLocale
    }

    /// set @lang to be the first in Applelanguages list
    class func setAppleLAnguageTo(lang: String) {
        let userdef = UserDefaults.standard
        userdef.set([lang,currentAppleLanguage()], forKey: APPLE_LANGUAGE_KEY)
        userdef.synchronize()
    }
```

I inherited LanguageViewController in all my FirstViewCOntroller, SecondController as below

```
class FirstViewController: LanguageViewController {

}
class SecondController: LanguageViewController {

}
```

If I call self.viewDidLoad() it fails to change language from view defined in storyboard. How to reload storyboard, so that the language should change in all viewcontroller,if any button from any viewcontroller is clicked?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NotificationCenter for reloading the view controllers content, this will also reload the content of view controllers that are not visible.

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let didChangeLanguage = Notification.Name("didChangeLanguage")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    //Add a listener
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onDidChangeLanguage(_:)), name: .didChangeLanguage, object: nil)

}

@IBAction func actionChange(_ sender: Any) {
    L102Language.currentAppleLanguage()
    L102Language.setAppleLAnguageTo(lang: "en")
    // Notify about the change.
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .didChangeLanguage, object: self, userInfo: nil)
}

@objc func onDidChangeLanguage(_ notification:Notification) {
    // reload content using selected language.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong. but I think you don't need to reload all view controllers. you just need to update them when they get displayed, view controllers are behind the presented one are not visible for the user.

for doing that you can do something like this:

```
var currentLanguage = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    currentLanguage = currentAppleLanguage()
    loadContentForLanguage(currentLanguage)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // this will be executed every time this sceen gets display
    if currentLanguage != currentAppleLanguage() {
          currentLanguage = currentAppleLanguage()
          loadContentForLanguage(currentLanguage)
    }
}

func loadContentForLanguage(_ currentLanguage: String) {
     //here it goes whatever you currently have in viewDidLoad
}
```

My apologies if this does not compile, my swift is really rusty.

Comment: No! I need to change language when pressing actionChange() button. Which is attached to all ViewControllers.